# Issue on multi level filtering DOM based on different data attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/30sj1ar2/). How can I enrich my code to have multi level filtering system based on different existing and potential upcoming data attributes?

As you can see I am trying to filter the `.box` based on two data attributes `shape` and `color` but my code is filtering the DOM separately. How can I fix this?

```
$('input:checkbox[name=shape]').on('change', function() {
   if ( $('input:checkbox[name=shape]:checked').length > 0)
   {
      $(".box").each(function(){
         $(this).removeClass('fadeInLeft').addClass('fadeOutLeft').css('display','none').css('display','none');
      });
      let data = [];
      $('input:checkbox[name=shape]:checked').each(function() {
         data.push($(this).data('shape'));
      });
      console.log(data);

      $.each(data, function(index, value){
         $('.box[data-shape="'+value+'"]').removeClass('fadeOutLeft').addClass('fadeInLeft').css('display','block');
      });
   }
   else
   {
      $(".box").each(function(){
         $(this).removeClass('fadeOutLeft').addClass('fadeInLeft').css('display','block');
      }); 
   }

});

$('input:checkbox[name=color]').on('change', function() {
   if ( $('input:checkbox[name=color]:checked').length > 0)
   {
      $(".box").each(function(){
         $(this).removeClass('fadeInLeft').addClass('fadeOutLeft').css('display','none').css('display','none');
      });

      let data = [];
      $('input:checkbox[name=color]:checked').each(function() {
         data.push($(this).data('color'));
      });


      $.each(data, function(index, value){
         $('.box[data-color="'+value+'"]').removeClass('fadeOutLeft').addClass('fadeInLeft').css('display','block');
      });
   }
   else
   {
      $(".box").each(function(){
         $(this).removeClass('fadeOutLeft').addClass('fadeInLeft').css('display','block');
      }); 
   }

});
```

Comment: this can be done very easily if you use CSS transitions for fading in/out. That way, all you'll need to do is add/remove a class to show/hide the boxes and the rest will be taken care by CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the checked condition as an array of objects and iterate all the `.box`.

```js
$("input:checkbox").on('change', function() {
  let condition = [];
  
  // save all the conditions that being checked
  $.each($("input:checkbox:checked"), function(ele, index) {
    let $this = $(this);
    let name = $this.attr('name');
    let data = $this.data(name);
    condition.push({
      name,
      data
    });
  })
  
  // hide all box
  $(".box").removeClass('fadeInLeft').addClass('fadeOutLeft').css('display','none');
  
  // iterate all box to check if matches any of the conditions
  if (condition.length != 0) {
    $('.box').each(function() {
      let $box = $(this);
      let checked = condition.find(x=> $box.data(x.name) == x.data ) != null;
      if(checked){
        $box.removeClass('fadeOutLeft').addClass('fadeInLeft').css('display','block');
      }
    })
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  padding: 40px;
}

.box {
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}

.green {
  background: green;
}

.yellow {
  background: yellow;
}

.diamond {
  height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  width: 60px;
}

.circle {
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 60px;
}

.square {
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="js-shape">
  <input type="checkbox" name="shape" data-shape="square">square
  <input type="checkbox" name="shape" data-shape="circle">circle
  <input type="checkbox" name="shape" data-shape="diamond">diamond
</div>

<div class="js-color">
  <input type="checkbox" name="color" data-color="red">Red
  <input type="checkbox" name="color" data-color="yellow">yellow
  <input type="checkbox" name="color" data-color="green">green


</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2 animated box red square" data-shape="square" data-color="red" data-size="70">70</div>
  <div class="col-md-2 animated box green circle" data-shape="circle" data-color="green" data-size="71">71</div>
  <div class="col-md-2 animated box yellow diamond" data-shape="diamond" data-color="yellow" data-size="70">70</div>
  <div class="col-md-2 animated box red diamond" data-shape="diamond" data-color="red" data-size="70">70</div>
  <div class="col-md-2 animated box green circle" data-shape="circle" data-color="green" data-size="71">71</div>
  <div class="col-md-2 animated box yellow square" data-shape="square" data-color="yellow" data-size="70">70</div>
  <div class="col-md-2 animated box red diamond" data-shape="diamond" data-color="red" data-size="70">70</div>
  <div class="col-md-2 animated box green circle" data-shape="circle" data-color="green" data-size="71">71</div>
  <div class="col-md-2 animated box yellow circle" data-shape="circle" data-color="yellow" data-size="70">70</div>
  <div class="col-md-2 animated box red diamond" data-shape="diamond" data-color="red" data-size="70">70</div>
  <div class="col-md-2 animated box green diamond" data-shape="diamond" data-color="green" data-size="71">71</div>
  <div class="col-md-2 animated box yellow square" data-shape="square" data-color="yellow" data-size="70">70</div>
  <div class="col-md-2 animated box red diamond" data-shape="diamond" data-color="red" data-size="70">70</div>
  <div class="col-md-2 animated box green diamond" data-shape="diamond" data-color="green" data-size="71">71</div>
  <div class="col-md-2 animated box yellow diamond" data-shape="diamond" data-color="yellow" data-size="70">70</div>
  <div class="col-md-2 animated box red square" data-shape="square" data-color="red" data-size="70">70</div>
  <div class="col-md-2 animated box green square" data-shape="square" data-color="green" data-size="71">71</div>
  <div class="col-md-2 animated box yellow diamond" data-shape="diamond" data-color="yellow" data-size="70">70</div>
  <div class="col-md-2 animated box red diamond" data-shape="diamond" data-color="red" data-size="70">70</div>
  <div class="col-md-2 animated box green square" data-shape="square" data-color="green" data-size="71">71</div>
  <div class="col-md-2 animated box yellow diamond" data-shape="diamond" data-color="yellow" data-size="70">70</div>
  <div class="col-md-2 animated box red circle" data-shape="circle" data-color="red" data-size="70">70</div>
  <div class="col-md-2 animated box green square" data-shape="square" data-color="green" data-size="71">71</div>
  <div class="col-md-2 animated box yellow diamond" data-shape="diamond" data-color="yellow" data-size="70">70</div>
</div>
```

BTW, IMO, I prefer using `class` instead of using `data-*`.